# Features of a Jet of Water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, projectile, shock-waves

Having created a water rocket that operates with compressed air forcing water out through a bottle's nozzle, I was interested in the some of the features of the jet of water that can be seen using slow motion video. In particular, can someone explain the mechanism that causes the three 'disc' structures that can be seen in the photo below? Is it to do with resonance of the bottle or a fluid dynamics property?

[image]

Comment: Those are most likely disruptions in the fluid flow due to a change in volume of the plastic bottle or air leakage during the streaming of the flow.

Answer (score 0):

It's because air gets into the water jet when the water is nearly all used up. I expect you know that the principle of the rocket relies on Newtons Third Law of Motion, so I wont bother you with details of that.